# Multiple upload file using React, Ruby on rails 5 and CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, file-upload, carrierwave

I've been stuck on a problem for about 2 days. I may be looking, but I can't find a post about it...

So, I use the Ruby on Rails framework with gem react on rails, and I try to make a multiple upload in react using the CarrierWave gem.

So the upload worked very well when there was only one file. But I adopted another strategy, it turned out that I finally had to be able to upload several files for a single model. So I created a polymorphic model (in case I need it elsewhere, it's more generic).

And so the problem is the moment I send the data from react to my controller. Indeed the JSON.stringify does not work with object File and I do not understand how I could do it...

**My controller**

```
  # POST /band_musics
  # POST /band_musics.json
  def create
    @band_music = BandMusic.new({
      :name => band_music_params[:name],
      :phone => band_music_params[:phone],
      :mail => band_music_params[:mail],
      :style => band_music_params[:style],
      :comment => band_music_params[:comment],
      :status => band_music_params[:status],
      :musics_attributes => JSON.parse(band_music_params[:musics_attributes]),
      :youtubes_attributes => JSON.parse(band_music_params[:youtubes_attributes])
    })
    respond_to do |format|
      if @band_music.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Le groupe a bien été enregisté' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @band_music }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @band_music.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**My band_music_params**

```
def band_music_params
  params.require(:band_music).permit(:name, :mail, :phone, :style, :comment, :status, :youtubes_attributes, :musics_attributes)
end
```

**My React Component**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDropzone from 'react-dropzone'

export default class GroupForm extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
  };

  /**
   * @param props - Comes from your rails view.
   */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      files: {},
      loading: false,
      disabled: true,
    };
  }

  submitGroupForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let response_files = {}
    Object.keys(this.state.files).map((file, index) => {
      response_files[index] = {
          'lastMod'    : this.state.files[file].sound.lastModified,
          'lastModDate': this.state.files[file].sound.lastModifiedDate,
          'name'       : this.state.files[file].sound.name,
          'size'       : this.state.files[file].sound.size,
          'type'       : this.state.files[file].sound.type,
      }
    });

    const file_array = JSON.stringify(response_files);

    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let formPayLoad = new FormData();
    formPayLoad.append('band_music[musics_attributes]', file_array);

    fetch(this.props.url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': ReactOnRails.authenticityToken(),
      },
      body: formPayLoad,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    });
  }

  onDrop = (files) => {
    if (Object.keys(this.state.files).length === 3) return
    var countFile = Object.keys(this.state.files).length
    console.log(countFile)
    files.forEach(file => {
      let hash = this.state.files
      hash[`${countFile}`] = { sound: file }
      this.setState({
        files: hash
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitGroupForm}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="sound" className="color-primary">
              Fichier(s) Audio(s)
            </label>
            <ReactDropzone
              accept="audio/*"
              onDrop={this.onDrop}
              className="react-drop-zone-css"
            >
              { Object.keys(this.state.files).length > 0 &&
                <div className="fileContainer">
                  {Object.keys(this.state.files).map((file) => (
                    <p className="file">
                      <i className="fa fa-music fa-2x mb-2"></i>
                      {this.state.files[file].sound.name}
                    </p>
                  ))}
                  { Object.keys(this.state.files).length < 1 &&
                    <p className="plus">
                      <i className="fa fa-plus fa-3x mb-2"></i>
                    </p>
                  }
                </div>
              }

              { Object.keys(this.state.files).length === 0 &&
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center w-100 h-100">
                  <p className="mb-0">Cliquez pour importer un fichier audio ! (3 fichiers max)</p>
                </div>
              }
            </ReactDropzone>
          </div>

          <div className="row justify-content-center">
            {
              !!this.state.loading ? (
                <input className="btn btn-lg bg-button color-white mt-3" type="submit" value="Chargement... Cette action peut prendre quelques minutes" />
              ) : (
                <input className={"btn btn-lg bg-button color-white mt-3 " + (!!this.state.disabled ? 'disabled' : '')} disabled={!!this.state.disabled} type="submit" value="S'inscrire au tremplin" />
              )
            }
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

To make it simple, how can you pass a file in parameters. Here I tried by transforming the file into a classic object for the stringify, it doesn't make any mistake but it doesn't save the file in the polymorphic model...

If you need me to post another file for more understanding, please say so in comment, thank you in advance :)

Comment: When it comes to handling the actual upload you might want to use [ActiveStorage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) if you can instead of CarrierWave - its really easy to handle file params and you can use the API for direct uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by just fixing the controller method:

```
  # POST /band_musics
  # POST /band_musics.json
  def create
    @band_music = BandMusic.new(band_music_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @band_music.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Le groupe a bien été enregisté' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @band_music }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @band_music.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

There is no actual point in:

1. Copying the hash keys like a human compiler. RoR has tons of hash methods like `Hash#slice` and `Hash#except` for that.
2. Manually JSON converting the nested attributes.

Instead you can whitelist nested attributes by passing a hash to `#permit`.

```
def band_music_params
  params.require(:band_music)
        .permit(
           :name, :mail, :phone, :style, :comment, :status, 
           youtubes_attributes: [:foo, :bar], 
           musics_attributes: [:lastMod, :lastModDate, :name, :size, :type]
        )
end
```

This permits an array of hashes with the attributes `[:lastMod, :lastModDate, :name, :size, :type]`. You should also of course remove the line in your react code that converts the objects to JSON strings:

```
// Don't do this.
const file_array = JSON.stringify(response_files);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick answer.

I tried the way you told me to do (that's what I did but when it didn't work, I improvised) :

**I changed the settings like this :**

```
params.require(:band_music).permit(:name, :mail, :phone, :style, :comment, :status, youtubes_attributes: [:url], musics_attributes: [:lastMod, :lastModDate, :name, :size, :type])
```

**My create function in controller**

```
# POST /band_musics
  # POST /band_musics.json
  def create
    @band_music = BandMusic.new(band_music_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @band_music.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Le groupe a bien été enregisté' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @band_music }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @band_music.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**My submitForm function**

```
submitGroupForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let response_files = {}
    Object.keys(this.state.files).map((file, index) => {
      response_files[index] = {
          'lastMod'    : this.state.files[file].sound.lastModified,
          'lastModDate': this.state.files[file].sound.lastModifiedDate,
          'name'       : this.state.files[file].sound.name,
          'size'       : this.state.files[file].sound.size,
          'type'       : this.state.files[file].sound.type,
      }
    });

    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let formPayLoad = new FormData();
    formPayLoad.append('band_music[musics_attributes]', response_files);

    fetch(this.props.url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': ReactOnRails.authenticityToken(),
      },
      body: formPayLoad,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    });
  }
```

**Here are the logs** :

```
Started POST "/band_musics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-07 14:34:36 +0100
Processing by BandMusicsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"band_music"=>{"name"=>"dqsdqsd", "musics_attributes"=>"[object Object]", "mail"=>"qsdqsdqsd", "phone"=>"090909", "style"=>"acid breaks", "comment"=>"dsqdqsdqsd", "youtubes_attributes"=>"[object Object]", "status"=>"pending"}}
Unpermitted parameters: :musics_attributes, :youtubes_attributes
```

There is a problem with the parameters and"[object, Object]"...

Comment: did you tried to add the attribute into the band_music[musics_attributes][image/whatever][] ?